# How to install all packages suggested by **TAB** auto-completion?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude, auto-completion

Is there any way to install all packages shown by pressing tab?
For example, I want to install all ***octave*** available packages.
When I type `# aptitude install octave` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> a list of packages that its name start by *octave* is shown.

```
aptitude install octave
octave                        octave-mpi
octave-bim                    octave-msh
octave-biosig                 octave-nan
octave-common                 octave-nlopt
octave-communications         octave-nurbs
octave-communications-common
--More--
```

How to install all of them?

I tried with `# aptitude install octave*` but it doesn't works.

Comment: Do you really need them all? Usually you install octave and aptitude installs all the dependencies needed.

Comment: I know that. What i really need is the command for install all of them. I want to install, for example, xfce full desktop environment.

Comment: Well this case would be `sudo aptitude install xubuntu-desktop` ;) but I got your question .. I'm just surprised `*` does not work..

Comment: What happens instead? Probably you run into concurrent packages or dependencies which cannot exist the Same time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aptitude does support regular expressions. From [`man aptitude`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/aptitude-curses.8.html):

```
install
   Install one or more packages. The packages should be listed after
   the “install” command; if a package name contains a tilde character
   (“~”) or a question mark (“?”), it will be treated as a search
   pattern and every package matching the pattern will be installed
   (see the section “Search Patterns” in the aptitude reference
   manual).
```

In fact its search system is sufficiently more powerful than apt's that you have to be more specific in what you want to search for. And `aptitude install 'octave?'` does try to install every package matching `octave` ... including those of any other architecture added to your system (say, `i386` on an `amd64` system). So, restricting the search a bit:

```
sudo aptitude install '?name (octave*) ?architecture (native)'
```

or, [in short](https://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s02.html):

```
sudo aptitude install '~n octave* ~r native'
```

... which tried to install 360+ packages compared to 38 from just `sudo aptitude install octave`.